# Git bisect run errors with You need to start by "git bisect start"

Tags: bash, git, git-for-windows, git-bisect

I have a `tests.sh` file.
The file simply contains either `exit 0` or `exit 1`. `0` for the first couple of commits, `1` for the remaining (I think) representing that the first couple of commits are `good` and the rest are `bad`.

I'm running `$ git bisect run ./tests.sh`.  However it's telling me I need to start with `git bisect start`.

```
$ git bisect run ./tests.sh
error: You need to start by "git bisect start".
You then need to give me at least one good|old and bad|new revision.
You can use "git bisect good|old" and "git bisect bad|new" for that.
```

I've tried running `git bisect start` first, and *kicking it off* by saying the `HEAD` is bad without success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So: you ran `git bisect start` and `git bisect bad HEAD`. What commit identifier did you supply to your `git bisect good` command?

Comment: That's it.  Thank you @torek.  I need to give it a good _and_ a bad and then it'll let me carry on with `run`.

Comment: I thought that the script should be telling it what was good abd bad, but obviously I need to give it a window to check within otherwise it would take forever in a large repo.